# urllib2.HTTPError Python

Tags: python, urllib2, biopython, ncbi

I have a file with GI numbers and would like to get `FASTA` sequences from ncbi.

```
from Bio import Entrez
import time
Entrez.email ="eigtw59tyjrt403@gmail.com"
f = open("C:\\bioinformatics\\gilist.txt")
for line in iter(f):
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=line, retmode="xml")
    records = Entrez.read(handle)
    print ">GI "+line.rstrip()+" "+records[0]["GBSeq_primary-accession"]+" "+records[0]["GBSeq_definition"]+"\n"+records[0]["GBSeq_sequence"]
    time.sleep(1) # to make sure not many requests go per second to ncbi
f.close()
```

This script runs fine but I suddenly get this error message after a few sequences.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ankur/PycharmProjects/ncbiseq/getncbiSeq.py", line 7, in <module>
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=line, retmode="xml")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Bio\Entrez\__init__.py", line 139, in efetch
    return _open(cgi, variables)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Bio\Entrez\__init__.py", line 455, in _open
    raise exception
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Of course I can use `http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sites/batchentrez` but I am trying to create a pipeline and would like something automated.

How can I prevent ncbi from "kicking me out"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the ncbi API, but my guess is that you're violating some kind of rate limiting rule (even with "sleep(1)" ), so your earlier requests work, but after a few requests the server sees that you're hitting it frequently and blocks you. This is problematic for you because you have no error handling in your code.

I'd recommend wrapping your data fetch in a try/except block to make your script wait longer and then try again if it encounters issues. If all else fails, write the id that caused the error to a file and continue on (in case the id is somehow the culprit, maybe causing the Entrez library to generate a bad URL).

Try changing your code to something like this (untested):

```
from urllib2 import HTTPError
from Bio import Entrez
import time

def get_record(_id):
    handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", id=_id, retmode="xml")
    records = Entrez.read(handle)
    print ">GI "+line.rstrip()+" "+records[0]["GBSeq_primary-accession"]+" "+records[0]["GBSeq_definition"]+"\n"+records[0]["GBSeq_sequence"]
    time.sleep(1) # to make sure not many requests go per second to ncbi

Entrez.email ="eigtw59tyjrt403@gmail.com"
f = open("C:\\bioinformatics\\gilist.txt")
for id in iter(f):
    try:
        get_record(id)
    except HTTPError:
        print "Error fetching", id
        time.sleep(5) # we have angered the API! Try waiting longer?
        try:
            get_record(id)
        except:
            with open('error_records.bad','a') as f:
                f.write(str(id)+'\n')
            continue # 
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a work around called efetch. You could split your list into batches of 200 (gut feeling this is an OK batch size) and use [efetch](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/) to send all these ids all at once.

First, this is MUCH, much faster than sending 200 individual queries. Second, it also effectively complies with the "3 queries per second" rule because the processing time per query is longer than 0.33 second but not too long.

However, you do need a mechanism to catch the "bad apples". NCBI will return 0 result even if one out of your 200 ids is bad. In other words, NCBI only returns results if and only if all your 200 ids are valid.

In case of bad apple, I iterate through the 200 ids one by one and ignore the bad apple. This "what if bad apple" scenario also tells you not to make the batch too big, just in case of bad apple. If it is big, first, the chance of having a bad apple is bigger, that is, you more often have to iterate the whole thing. Second, the larger the batch, the more individual items you have to iterate.

I use the following code to download the CAZy proteins and it works well:

```
import urllib2


prefix = "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=protein&rettype=fasta&id="
id_per_request = 200


def getSeq (id_list):
    url = prefix + id_list[:len(id_list)-1]

    temp_content = ""
    try:
        temp_content += urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

### if there is a bad apple, try one by one
    except:
        for id in id_list[:len(id_list)-1].split(","):
            url = prefix + id
    #print url
            try:
                temp_content += urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
            except:
            #print id
                pass
    return temp_content


content = ""
counter = 0
id_list = ""

#define your accession numbers first, here it is just an example!!

accs = ["ADL19140.1","ABW01768.1","CCQ33656.1"]
for acc in accs:

    id_list += acc + ","
    counter += 1

    if counter == id_per_request:
        counter = 0
        content += getSeq(id_list)
        id_list = ""

if id_list != "":
    content += getSeq(id_list)
    id_list = ""


print content
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a "normal" Entrez API temporary fail which can occur even if you've applied all Entrez API rules. Biopython documentation explains a way to handle it in [this section](https://biopython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Tutorial/chapter_entrez.html#searching-for-and-downloading-sequences-using-the-history).

> Sometimes you will get intermittent errors from Entrez, HTTPError 5XX, we use a try except pause retry block to address this. For example,
>
> ```
> # This assumes you have already run a search as shown above,
> # and set the variables count, webenv, query_key
>
> try:
>     from urllib.error import HTTPError  # for Python 3
> except ImportError:
>     from urllib2 import HTTPError  # for Python 2
>
> batch_size = 3
> out_handle = open("orchid_rpl16.fasta", "w")
> for start in range(0, count, batch_size):
>     end = min(count, start+batch_size)
>     print("Going to download record %i to %i" % (start+1, end))
>     attempt = 0
>     while attempt < 3:
>         attempt += 1
>         try:
>             fetch_handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide",
>                                          rettype="fasta", retmode="text",
>                                          retstart=start, retmax=batch_size,
>                                          webenv=webenv, query_key=query_key,
>                                          idtype="acc")
>         except HTTPError as err:
>             if 500 <= err.code <= 599:
>                 print("Received error from server %s" % err)
>                 print("Attempt %i of 3" % attempt)
>                 time.sleep(15)
>             else:
>                 raise
>     data = fetch_handle.read()
>     fetch_handle.close()
>     out_handle.write(data)
> out_handle.close()
> ```

So you don't to feel guilty about this error and just have to catch it.

Comment: Thanks for your review.
I thought the initial question was `How can I prevent ncbi from "kicking me out"`. Perhaps I wasn't clear enough, my answer would explain that, firstly, the error received by OP doesn't mean NCBI API "kick him out" and, secondly, how to handle this exception according to the documentation of Biopython, the tool OP used.
Which part do you think I can improve to answer more accurately to the question?

Comment: @BiBizz I was wrong-footed by your opening remark *Experiencing the same error* which immediately suggests an "I'm having this problem too" type answer. Which, on consideration, I can see that it isn't really. Withdrawing the review.

Comment: You're right it's a poor introduction which is not very useful. I remove it to be more direct.
Thanks for your helpful review.